# How to change skins in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, skin

I have a very basic question, but I don't know the answer, unfortunately, google-ing didn't help.

I have a solution where I have two projects, project A and project B. Both of them use a Default.skin file for theme-ing in their AppThemes. However, I want to use Default.skin from project B in project A if a certain condition is met. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@Page` directive and set `Theme` or `StyleSheetTheme`. There are some [scope differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx#ScopingThemes) depending on what you use.

You can also set it in the web.config on the `<pages>` element.  [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363.aspx).

Or, you can set it [programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx) in `Page_PreInit` by setting `Page.Theme`, which may be what you need if you need to set it conditionally depending on A or B.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have `configured` [global](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de93t31k%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [theme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163711.aspx). Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx) article - [How to: Apply ASP.NET Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yy5hxdk.aspx).